# Excel 2010 - Drag formula to the right but make relative reference go down

Tags: excel, reference

I want to split a weekly budget on daily requested spend, in order to arrive at the end of the week with no budget left. To accomplish the task I've estimated the requested daily spend as a percentage of the whole budget. I've saved the percentages to use in each day in the range `A7:B13` in a worksheet named "Assumption". On column A I wrote the day (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, etc..) and on column B the percentages (8%, 8%, 8%, 15%, etc.. which summed results on 100%).

On the worksheet "Summary" I have on the range `B2:B11` budget for each client. On the same sheet I've inserted the days (Monday, Tuesday, etc..) on the range `C1:I1`.

Now, I would like to insert a formula in cell `C2` on the "Summary" sheet that I can drag to use on the whole range `C1:I11`.

Now the issue is that being the percentages stored "vertically" I can't use a straightforward `=$B2*Assumption!B$7`

I don't want to transpose the range in the "Assumption" sheet either. I've done it to complete the task, however I would like to learn how get around it for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `VLOOKUP` formula, e.g. in C2 copied down and across

`=VLOOKUP(C$1,Assumption!$A$7:$B$13,2,0)`

which specifically relates the % to the day

for a formula which just picks up each % sequentially, not necessarily matching days, try this in C2 copied down and across

`=INDEX(Assumption!$B$7:$B$13,COLUMNS($C2:C2))`

Comment: Hi Barry! thanks to your input I found the solution. The right formula to use is `=$B2*VLOOKUP(C$1,Assumption!$A$7:$B$13,2,FALSE)`. I've used a `VLOOKUP` instead of the `HLOOKUP`.

Comment: Thanks Gianluca, I had already realised my error and edited to use VLOOKUP...I missed out the $B2* bit though.......

Answer (score 0):

The right formula to insert in cell `C2` is:

`=$B2*VLOOKUP(C$1,Assumption!$A$7:$B$13,2,FALSE)`